# Testlink login error

Tags: testlink

I have installed and configured testlink 1.9.16 on centos7 server using following link 
https://sysadmin.compxtreme.ro/how-to-install-testlink-on-centos-6-3/

I made some changes according to my Centos7

after completing all procedure, when i open **IP_of_my_server/login.php**
i get following error message

============================================================================== 
 DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 
            Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
            issue to development TEAM. 
 ==============================================================================

my log entry is

**ERROR ON exec_query() - database.class.php 
 -  - /* Class:tlEvent -  Method: writeToDB */ INSERT INTO events**

**(transaction_id,log_level,description,source,fired_at,object_id,object_type,activity) VALUES (0,2,'','',1503033721,0,NULL,'')
THE MESSAGE : /* Class:tlEvent - Method: writeToDB */ INSERT INTO events** **(transaction_id,log_level,description,source,fired_at,object_id,object_type,activity) VALUES (0,2,'','',1503033721,0,NULL,'')
Query failed: errorcode[]
        errormsg:**

My mysql version is **mysql  Ver 5.6.37 for Linux on x86_64** 
and my PHP version is **PHP 5.6.31 (cli)**

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same problem. Looks like installer problem. Just set password for testlink database user. Something like:

> grant all privileges on testlink.* to 'testlink'@'localhost' identified by 'your_password';

The password must be the same as in the file config.inc.php in your testlink directory. 'DB_PASS' option.

Comment: To check that everything is OK test your db connection from server console, i.e. mysql -h localhost -u testlink -pyour_password testlink